# General IDE / VC

Tags: version-control, ide

I'm developing a django site using pycharm (Windows desktop) & a github repo for a site on a remote Linux box with an SSH connection. It's a fairly small, one person project (at present). 
It's all working, but I don't think I'm working very efficiently. Every change & test seems laborious. I don't want to be making commits every time I make a small change but I'm still new enough that I need to be making lots of tests as I go along. 
So what would people's general workflow be? Have a local test install with a copy of the django site and work directly on that? What's the best way to update the live site (from github). 
If there's any standard best practice docs out there that you can point to would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be making commits for every small change. But making a commit doesn't mean deploying; you should develop and test locally, and commit your changes locally. When you have a finished feature, that's when you should deploy.